# Django blog with picture

Tags: django, django-templates, blogs

I have this in my database

paragraph1

paragraph2

paragraph2

I would like to place a picture in between paragraphs.

I tried this

```
<img src="where/photo/is">

class Post(models.Model):
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('draft','Draft'),
    ('published', 'Published'),
)

title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date ='publish')
author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='blog_posts')
body = models.TextField()
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts', default='path/to/my/default/image.jpg')
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
    default='draft')
objects = models.Manager()
published = PublishedManager()
tags = TaggableManager()

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('blog:post_detail',
            args=[self.slug])
```

Note: This is the post table that takes the data in paragraphs, there is not picture in between, I would like to add it after getting this text body.

Here is my view

```
current_site = get_current_site(request)
namesite = current_site.name
domain = current_site.domain

post = Post.published.get(slug=post)

profile = Profile.objects.get(id=1)


if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        #create Comment object but do not say to database just yet
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
        #Assigng the current post to the comment
        new_comment.post = post
        #save the comment to the database
        new_comment.save()
        comment_form = CommentForm()
else:
    comment_form = CommentForm()

return render(request, 'blog/detail.html',
                {'post': post, 'comments': comments, 
                 'comment_form': comment_form, 'namesite': namesite, 'domain': domain, 'profile': profile })
```

in the database and I use the | safe filter, but that still prints the same as above.

Do you have any idea how to perform that acction?

Comment: So, what I mean is , i get the text from the database, but I do not have a picture that goes with it, I want to added from my images. Do you see the problem?

Comment: share you code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi If you want to create long description with image means you can go with django-ckeditor [link](http://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/INSTALL/), this package will provide you the RichTextField so you can create the bulk paragraphs with images.